# Instantiating classes in python - setting attributes

Tags: java, python, attributes, constructor, global

Coming from a Java background, I want a class to have certain attributes and set them in the constructor.

Currently I use the global keyword
eg.

```
def class A():

 global attribute1
 global attribute2

 __init__():
  attribute1 = 1
  attribute2 = 2
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Reason I am asking is because I am not sure whether setting all attributes "Global" is correct.

EDIT: Also, whenever I access the attributes, I need self.attribute ... is this necessary? i.e. in java you dont require this.attribute all the time.

Comment: Yes, you always need `self.attribute`. It makes it clear where the variable that you're referring to is.

Comment: Since your example code is neither valid syntax nor anywhere close to working, I'd advice you to read a Python book or tutorial after trying to forget anything you know about Java and the way things are done there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right way to do this is to add the attributes to the constructor and add them on your instance.

```
>>> class A(object):
...    def __init__(self, attribute1, attribute2):
...        self.attribute1 = attribute1
...        self.attribute2 = attribute2
...

>>> a = A(1, 2)
>>> a.attribute1
1
>>> a.attribute2
2
```

As for your second question, yes, you need to use `self.attribute` within the instance to refer to it.

Comment: this makes a lot of sense. Out of curiosity, when would the global keyword come in handy? When we want to modify the attributes?

Comment: Use global keyword when you need to modify (assign) a global reference in a fuction. Otherwise a new local would be created.